# Drawing with tikz knots package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

The [manual for tikz Knots package](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/spath3/knots_doc.pdf) has this example:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots} 
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,4) [draw,minimum width=30pt, minimum height=10pt , thick ] {}; 
\begin{knot}[clip width=5, clip radius=8pt]
\strand [thick, only when rendering/.style={dashed}] (0,0) 
to [out=up, in=down] (−1,1)
to [out=up, in=down] (0,2)
to [out=up, in=down] (−1.2,4)
to [out=up, in=down, looseness=0.7] (0,5.5) 
to [out=up, in=down] (−2,7);
\strand [ thick ] (−1,0)
to [out=up, in=down]  (1,2)
to [out=up, in=down] (A.south);
\strand [ thick, blue] (1,0)
to [out=up, in=down] (-1, 2)
to [out=up, in=down] (1.5, 4)
to [out=up, in=right] (0,5.5) to [out=left, in=up] (−2,4) 
to [out=down, in=up] (−2,0);
\strand [ thick ] (A.150)
to [out=up, in=down] (0.7,5.5) 
to [out=up, in=down] (0,7); 
\strand [ thick ] (A.30)
to [out=up, in=down] (−1,6)
to [out=up, in=down] (2,7); 
\flipcrossings {6,2,9,5,11} 
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, latexing it produces this error. How can I fix it?

> 11: Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> \protect.
> l.11 to [out=up, in=down] (−1,1)

Comment: Your minus signs are some non-ASCII characters. Why this happened, I do not know. However, once I replace them by ASCII `-` signs, and add some document class command, it works.

Comment: Thanks so much! I copied it from the pdf manual into tex and didn't realize the minus issue. Since this is not a tikz issue, I will delete this question.

Comment: You're welcome! (In some way it is a TeX issue since non-ASCII characters can do a lot of harm, and the error messages aren't that illuminating, as your case illustrates. From this point of view your post can help others who run into the same problem figure out what's wrong with their code.)

Comment: Upon your comment, I will keep my question here, in case others fall into this trap.

Comment: My own experience says that others did. ;-) The question is indeed what the most useful way is to share the information with the LaTeX community. Maybe it is keeping the question, changing the title to something like "Why does the code copied from the manual not work?", add some appropriate document class command, and write an answer (or let someone else write an answer, I'd be happy to do that or someone with more experience could do it). What I like about your post is that you post the error message as text, so Google can find it.

Comment: Looking at the date on the pdf, that looks quite an old file. I suspect this issue might have been fixed on github, but because it was only a documentation problem I probably didn't upload it to ctan. I probably should do so.